# Is there anyway I can open a PDF from UI made from Angular/JS in Acrobat from one button click

Tags: java, angular, acrobat, ngx-extended-pdf-viewer

I'm currently implementing an Angular/java webpage to work with different forms for the users.
right now if the users want to edit the pdf, the only way is to download the PDF and go to the downloads folder and open it in Adobe acrobat. Which is not an optimal solution.

Is there any way I can create a button in HTML/Angular webpage that can automate this process to open the PDF in Adobe acrobat? instead of downloading and going to download folder and open it from there?

I tried to use ngx-extended-pdf-viewer to edit the pdf in the browser. But the user needs to highlight, stamp, and email features that are in Acrobat. Does anyone have a solution for this?
thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can display the pdf file in new tab by the line:

```
window.open(fileUrl, '_blank');
```

The fileUrl is a variable that contains the file path. You can fetch it after the download is complete.